How do I keep the container spawned by the docker operator running?
I am using Airflow 2.9.0 and the idea I am trying to accomplish is that Docker container/s are created in one task, then the next task uses that running container for something, then I have a task at the end clean up after I am done. The problem I am having (and I think I am missing something conceptually regarding Airflow and I'm not sure where to start) is that once the docker task runs and the next task start, the docker container is no longer present.
Here's what my code generally looks like, I have a dag and a task the uses DockerOperator that looks like this:
@dag(
    dag_id="some_id",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
)
def some_dag():
    # def task_1(): ...

    @task
    def start_some_container():
        DockerOperator(
                    task_id="start_some_container",
                    image="some_image:latest",
                    api_version="auto",
                    docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
                    cap_add=["NET_ADMIN"],
                    privileged=True,
                    port_bindings={4444: '4000-6000'},
                    container_name=f"some_container_name_{int(time.time())}_{uuid.uuid4()}",
                    xcom_all=True,
                    network_mode="some-network",
        )
 
    # def task_2(): ... # should do something using the container
    # def cleanup_docker_container(): ... # Thinking of using BashOeprator to run `docker container stop`

    task_1()
    start_some_container()
    task_2()
    cleanup_docker_container()

run_dag = some_dag()

I've greatly simplified my code for purpose of my question. I know that the DockerOperator works for my current needs as I've tested it inside the Python Interpreter and even used it inside an airflow task at first, but, while it launches the container and keeps it running, that seems to block everything else inside the task from running; e.g:
def task_2():
    DockerOperator(
                task_id="start_some_container",
                image="some_image:latest",
                api_version="auto",
                docker_url="unix://var/run/docker.sock",
                cap_add=["NET_ADMIN"],
                privileged=True,
                port_bindings={4444: '4000-6000'},
                container_name=f"some_container_name_{int(time.time())}_{uuid.uuid4()}",
                xcom_all=True,
                network_mode="some-network",
    )

    # Other things to do in this task, outside the container, but blocked from running.

I'm basically stuck at this point. Either I am missing something conceptually about Airflow, or the way I am designing the dag and its tasks is bad in the first place. I'm hoping that it's the first.
